# Accelerometer with Low passfilter in Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, lowpass-filter

I want to use the accelerometer in android for my app.
In documentation its given as below:

```
   final float alpha = 0.8;

   // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.

   gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
```

But lowpass filter works as below:

```
    output = alpha*input + (1-alpha)*previousoutput;
```

My query is why we are taking gravity as input and sensor event as previous output?
It must be other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it uses linear mix of two inputs: `mix(α,x,y) = α * x + (1-α) * y`.

Now `mix(α,x,y)` is equivalent to `mix(1-α,y,x)`.
So you can reverse signals as you wanted, make `alpha = 0.2` and everything will work the same.

Comment: Thanks got it. Problem is i confused with alpha as time-constant and i am not aware of linear mix.